# How to Use D3 charts with angular 2 or 4

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts

I want to use D3 charts in one of my projects please help.

I tried following the installation process. but it's not working properly peasen provide me another solution so can implement it in the existing project.

```
npm install d3-ng2-service --save

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { D3Service } from 'd3-ng2-service'; // <-- import statement

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestD3Component // <-- declaration of the D3 Test component used below
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [D3Service], // <-- provider registration
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: Well, what's your error ? This seems OK to me

Comment: r u getting any errors in console ? If so pls post them .

Answer (score 10):

There are two implementation of D3 charts

1.ng2-nvd3 charts

2.ngx charts

So i am going to implement ng2-nvd3 charts

**also can clone it from** 
https://github.com/DevInder1/ng2-nvd3-charts

Firstly Need to Install it

```
npm install ng2-nvd3 --save
```

Then import it in NgModule and also need to import d3 and nvd3 as i am importing below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'd3';
import 'nvd3'
import {NvD3Module} from "ng2-nvd3";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NvD3Module,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After this you have to Add style in .angular-cli.json File

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css"
      ],
```

Next you have to go to your component.ts file in this example i am using 
  app.component.ts and you have to provide data and option object to the chart 
  directive

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  options: any;
  data: any;


  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'pieChart',
        height: 500,
        x: function (d) {
          return d.key;
        },
        y: function (d) {
          return d.y;
        },
        showLabels: true,
        duration: 500,
        labelThreshold: 0.01,
        labelSunbeamLayout: true,
        legend: {
          margin: {
            top: 5,
            right: 35,
            bottom: 5,
            left: 0
          }
        }
      }
    };

    this.data = [
      {
        key: "P60-1",
        y: 256
      },
      {
        key: "P60-2",
        y: 445
      },
      {
        key: "P40",
        y: 225
      },
      {
        key: "P73",
        y: 127
      },
      {
        key: "P71",
        y: 128
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

once it is done in your Html need to provide Chart directive in my example it is app.component.html

```
<div>
  <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>
</div>
```

Comment: git repo seems to be a blank project in angular, nothing related to charts. Can you please update the code.

Answer (score 0):

**End to end solution for ngx-nvd3. angular 6**

**Requirements:**

```
1.Install "d3": "^3.5.17"
2.Install "ngx-nvd3": "^1.0.9"
```

**app.module.ts(appModule)**

```
import { NvD3Module } from 'ngx-nvd3'
imports: [NvD3Module]
```

**admin.component.html(HTML)**

```
<div>
    <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="datas"> 
    </nvd3>
</div>
```

**admin.component.ts (Component .ts file)**

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

datas:any

styleUrls: ['./adminpanel.component.css','../../../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css']

this.options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'discreteBarChart',
    height: 450,
    margin: {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 55
    },
    x: function (d) {
      return d.label;
    },
    y: function (d) {
      return d.value + (1e-10);
    },
    showValues: true,
    valueFormat: function (d) {
      return d3.format(',.4f')(d);
    },
    duration: 500,
    xAxis: {
      axisLabel: 'X Axis'
    },
    yAxis: {
      axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
      axisLabelDistance: -10
    }
  }
};

  this.datas = [
    {
      key: "Cumulative Return",
      values: [
        {
          "label" : "A" ,
          "value" : -29.765957771107
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "B" ,
          "value" : 0
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "C" ,
          "value" : 32.807804682612
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "d" ,
          "value" : 60.807804682612
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "e" ,
          "value" : 70.807804682612
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "f" ,
          "value" : 80.807804682612
        } ,
      ]
    }
  ];
```